# How Can I Get PowerShell to Execute MpCmdRun.exe

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

PowerShell runs programs such as IpConfig and WhoAmI just as cmd would.  However, I am stumped trying to run MpCmdRun.exe

> Clear-Host 
> Set-Location "C:\Program Files\Windows Defender"
> Get-ChildItem 
> mpcmdrun.exe

Result

> Error:
>
> mpcmdrun.exe : The term 'mpcmdrun.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
> program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing `mpcmdrun.exe`. You have to do `.\mpcmdrun.exe` as the current folder `.` is not in PATH in Powershell unlike in cmd.

PS:

I wonder if you read the entire message that Powershell would have spit out when you did as you said:

> Suggestion [3,General]: The command MpCmdRun.exe was not found, but
>   does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load
>   commands from the current location by default. If you trust this
>   command, instead type ".\MpCmdRun.exe". See "get-help
>   about_Command_Precedence" for more details.

PPS:

The other commands ran because they were in PATH.